# VS2005 C++0X not fully supported

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2005

I have a project created in VS2012, and I want use the source code to build a DLL with VS2005. How can I compile it with the error: C++0X not fully supported?

For example there are many errors like: 
error C2061: unique_ptr is not a member of 'std'
error C2039: enable_if is not a member of 'std'
error C3861: move is not a member of 'std'
I don't know how to change the code so it can be complied, is there a link or something I can learn to solve the problem? Any suggestion would be appreciate.

Comment: That's not going to work. C++0x was finalized in 2011. That's why it is supported (mostly) in VS2012. There's no way in which VS2005 could foresee what the Standard would say 6 years later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++11 is not supported in VS.NET 2005 as MSalters stated in the comments. Even VS.NET 2015 Does not support all C++11 standards. You may find more details in this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

**EDIT:**
I have just remember something. There is an option in Visual studio to use another compiler that microsoft one. You may search for some one that worked on VS.NET 2005 and in the same time supports C++ 11. However, I do not know if it is exist. Another thing, it is not a good idea becuase you gonna face many problems due the compatibility.

Comment: May be  Intel C++ Compiler can do that. So if I want to build it in VS2005, I must rewrite the corresponding code, Wow,it's much complicated than I thought..

Comment: @SuperYoung: Why are you so attached to VS2005, which is 10 years old (more than a lifetime in technology)?  There's [a free edition of the new one](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs).

Comment: not me, It's our company. All the products must based on VS2005. ==!